# Determining a power series of $f(z)=\exp(z^{2})$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Let $f(z)=\exp(z^{2})$. Determine a power series of $f$, i.e the coefficients $a_{k}$ such that $f(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_{k}z^{k}$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, where $a_{k}=f^{(k)}(0)/k!$.

First we have $$f^{(1)}(z)=2zf(z)\\f^{(2)}(z)=2f(z)+2zf^{(1)}(z)\\f^{(3)}(z)=4f^{(1)}(z)+2zf^{(2)}(z)\\
f^{(4)}(z)=6f^{(2)}(z)+2zf^{(3)}(z)\\
f^{(n)}(z)=2(n-1)f^{(n-2)}(z)+2zf^{(n-1)}(z)$$
for all $n\geq 5$.
I have observed that $f^{(k)}(0)=0$ for all $k\in 2\mathbb{N}_{0}+1$. Thus we get $f(0)=1$,  $f^{(2)}(0)=2$, $f^{(4)}(0)=12$, $f^{(6)}(0)=120$, $f^{(8)}(0)=1680$ etc. How do I then determine $a_{k}$?

Comment: Why not find the power series for $\exp(z)$ and then replace $z$ with $z^2$?

Comment: @Lemon, I was aware of it. When using the method $\exp(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}z^{k}$, I would get $\exp(z^{2})=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}(z^2)^{k}$. I am not sure if that's what the problem told me to determine other than $a_{k}$ while the expression of $z^{k}$ is "changed". Is there not another way to do as I have shown in OP?

Comment: "Determine a power series..." I'd reather say "Determine **the** power series..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 
$$e^z = \sum_{n\ge 0} {z^n\over n!},$$
then you have
$$e^{z^2} = \sum_{n\ge 0} {z^{2n}\over n!}.$$
These series both converge globally.

Comment: Except that $z_n$ should be $z^n$ :)

Comment: I have placed the needed ^.